How to check what is resulting in global (all tables) SELECT permissions granted for guest user account?
Sp_helpprotect @username='guest'
This shows that guest has SELECT permission on Object .
Effectively meaning that any SQL login that doesn't have corresponding database user account mapping can fire SELECT queries.
I understand . possibly means everything.
In the user properties, under securables I cannot see where this is assigned. I tried checking the securables: tables, schemas.. but none have SELECT given explicitly. Where can I check on the UI on what exactly the permission is explicitly given that provides user with SELECT on everything?

What AD Groups does this user belong to?

It's the guest user

Guest in what context?...Windows doesn't really use guest accounts anymore. Are you sure it's not an AD user (or SQL Login) just called guest?

I'm referring to the default guest database user account that exists in all databases.

No wonder I never heard about it. It's a legacy account that's a potential security hole where best practice is to disable it. Consequently that would fix your issue too. So why not revoke Connect access from it?

Yes that's the plan. But generally in the UI is there any way the see how it has been given the SELECT permission on Object .

I guess why does it matter if you're going to disable it, as per best practice anyway?

Could you specify the complete result set?
For example, the following means that the user guest has the CONNECT permission on the database, nothing else.
+-------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+--------+
| Owner | Object | Grantee | Grantor | ProtectType | Action  | Column |
+-------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+--------+
|     . |      . | guest   | dbo     | Grant       | CONNECT |      . |
+-------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+--------+

The . for the object is just a placeholder. CONNECT only has effect at the database. It does not mean it's a specifically "high" permission.
I suspect that this is exactly what you have there.
If this is the master database, then this is expected and required. If this is in a user database, then this is a risk and should be revoked, unless there really is a strong requirement and no alternative.
Lastly, just don't use that special proc at all. It is out of support and does not return complete information. Query the catalog views.
The following statement would give you the same information but much more complete:
SELECT * FROM sys.database_permissions WHERE grantee_principal_id = USER_ID('guest')


Thank you John for prettifying :)

When user has permission that appears to apply to all objects (.), it usually means that the permission has been granted at higher level, like the database or server level, instead of objects like tables or schemas.
If the permission is not exclusively granted at the table or schema level, it is likely granted at the database level or through a role membership.
So check at the higher levels.

User doesn't have any database or server level role. Only public.

If user only has the public role and yet has SELECT permissions on all objects, it is possible that the public role itself has been given SELECT permissions at higher level

The login exists on server. But not on database.
